# Troubleshooting post request issue from safari (iphone) to a production server

Tags: .net, safari, windows-authentication, antiforgerytoken

After a recent deployment to production, a js post request stopped working when made from safari on mobile and I'm looking for some help troubleshooting.

The weird thing is, the same code works in the test environment. The request also works when sent from any desktop browser that I've been able to try (which is only IE and Edge, reasons in the next paragraph)

What makes this worse is that the environments are secured behind vpn and locked down which means I cannot troubleshoot it as I would usually do. E.g. I cannot install the desktop version of safari - or any other tooling - to reproduce the error with something that has a console. Nor can I examine the network from a client. This means that I don't even know if the request is actually posted or if the fault occurs before that.

The IIS server logs doesn't not show any of these faulty requests, so is that a guarantee that the request hasn't been sent and that it is a client issue? - But then if it is a code issue on the client, it shouldn't work in the test environment, right?

So, what's different about the test environment compared to production? Well it's not in the DMZ so maybe there's a network issue occurring between safari and the production server… but only for this specific http post request?

Ok, so another thing that might be relevant is that this request uses .net antiforgerytoken which I've seen some issues with in combination with windows authentication and safari when searching here on SO - but shouldn't that generate something in the iis log, like forbidden or a 401? Besides the test environment is setup with the same authentication and negotiate + NTLM providers so could this really have something to do with the antiforgery?

The antiforgerytoken was added to this release. Also the request changed path (to a different controller) and went from being a "GET" to being a "POST".

Becuase the IIS logs doesn't show anything for these requests and I can't use any other client than an Iphone to reproduce, I have no error messages to provide. (The windows event viewer doesn't show anything either).

I expect it would work just as it does in the test environment because the code is the same - the only actual difference I can Think of is that the production server is in the DMZ. So any ideas for troubleshooting this further?

Comment: Is the POST request going to a different domain than what the website is on (or even HTTP/HTTPS version of the same site)? If the protocol, domain name and port of the website you're on doesn't match the website you're trying to access via JavaScript, then it could be a [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) issue.

Comment: That's a good point, thanks. The request is on the same domain and the url for the request is generated serverside and uses the current scheme "Request.Url.Scheme":

Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Authority + Request.ApplicationPath + [controller/method].

Comment: So then does that end up matching exactly with the address in the address bar of the browser?

Comment: You can try connecting it to a Mac and using the Web Inspector: https://www.lifewire.com/activate-the-debug-console-in-safari-445798

Comment: That's a good idea too but I don't think I'll be able to - in order to browse the web page a vpn-connection is needed and there's no Mac's around. Also there's too many levels of bureaucracy to get a certificate installed on a machine that isn't issued as standard.

Comment: Do your IIS logs show OPTIONS requests? If you see an OPTIONS request to the URL, but not the following POST, then that will tell you it is a CORS issue.

Comment: Finally the issue is resolved. Sad to say that I still don't know why this worked, but I do know what we did to resolve it. We simply switched from absolute URL for the post to a relative one. The absolute URL worked all tested browser except safari for Iphone in production, the test environment always worked - so strange... I guess the lesson here is to use relative urls wherever possible. Thank you @GabrielLuci for your efforts.